# Multiple controllers in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, controller

I m new to cakephp...
      I m developing an app using CakePhp  and Mysql.
      In Cakephp i am  having two tables one is Form (id ,name,created , modified) and attributes (id, Attribute-name ,form_id ,value)
    I kept everything in only one controller that is in forms controller.Within this formsctrller , i m having actions like login ,register,viewforms...

```
 Do i need to create a separate controller for login and register..If so Actually i will run in my system with http://localhost/cake/forms where i am having the place to register and login ...If i had separate controller,then how can i make that to switch from forms to login controller on login....Explain me...
```

Edit

```
<?php
 class UsersController extends AppController 
{
 var $name = 'Users';
var $helpers=array('Html','Ajax','Javascript','Form');
 var $components = array( 'RequestHandler','Email');
 var $uses=array('Form','User','Attribute');
//Function for login 
function login()
   {
    $email_id=$this->data['User']['email_id'];
        $password=$this->data['User']['password'];
    $login=$this->User->find('all');
    $this->set('Forms',$this->Form->find('all'));
    foreach($login as $form):
        if($email_id==$form['User']['email_id'] && $password==$form['User']['password'])
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Successful');
                            // $this->render('forms/homepage');
            $this->redirect('/forms/homepage');


            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login UnSuccessful');
            //$this->redirect('/forms/index');
        }
    endforeach;


}

//Function to register the user into Users Table.
function register()
{
           $this->set('Forms',$this->Form->find('all'));
    if (!empty($this->data)) 
    {
        if ($this->User->save($this->data)) 
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('You have been registered.');
            $this->set('register', $this->Form->find('all'));
                            //$this->render('homepage');
            $this->redirect('/forms/homepage');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Ya Now i am using two controllers One for Users and One for Forms .
But One Doubt .I have run the above code..Actually in my /forms/index.ctp

```
      <?php
     echo $javascript->link('prototype.js');
     echo $javascript->link('scriptaculous.js');
    echo $html->css('main.css');
   ?>
```

### formBuildr

#### Register

```
          <?php
           echo $form->create('User',array('action'=>'register'));
           echo $form->input('User.name');
          echo $form->input('User.email_id');
          echo $form->input('User.password');
           echo $form->end('Register');
          ?>
   </div>

     <div id="login">
    <h3>Login</h3>
        <?php
                echo $form->create('User',array('action'=>'login'));
                echo $form->input('User.email_id');
                echo $form->input('User.password');
                echo $form->end('Login');
         ?>
      </div>
```

I have registered and login ..It goes /forms/homepage But the thing is that ..It doesn't show me the Flash message Of (Login successfull/Unsucessfull) I tried with render option , but even showing me the error..
Note :Since i no need to have anything in my views/users/login.ctp i am not having login.ctp..(SINCE I M LOGIN IN AND DIRECTLY MOVES TO HE HOMEPAGE OF MY FORMSCONTROLLER.

Comment: Please reformat this so it's readable... And use complete words not abbreviations.

Answer (score 4):

You obviously haven't done your homework. I suggest you read Cake's official [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org).

To answer your question. If you want to handle login and user registration, you should actually

1. Create a new table called `users` (id, username, password)
2. Create `class User extends AppModel` as `app/models/user.php`
3. Create `class UsersController extends AppController` as `app/controllers/users_controller.php`
4. You should put `login()` and `register()` in your `UsersController`.

Now, to *switch* from one controller to another controller, you provide a hyperlink.

```
<a href="/cake/users">Users</a>
<a href="/cake/forms">Manage your forms</a>
```

Or, a more Cake-ish approach

```
<?php echo $html->link("Users", '/users');?>
<?php echo $html->link("Manage your forms", '/forms');?>
```

Serious though, if you have further questions, you're advised to [RTFM](http://book.cakephp.org).

*Edit: If submit an HTML form from `/forms` to `/users`, there's no automagic redirection. So if you want the users go be redirected, you'd need to do this*

```
<?php 

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    function login()
    {
        if(!empty($this->data))
        {
            // Process $_POST

            // Finally redirect the user back to forms
            $this->redirect('/forms');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: <div id="register">
<h3>Register</h3>
<?php
echo $form->create('Form',array('action'=>'register'));
echo $form->input('User.name');
echo $form->input('User.email_id');
echo $form->input('User.password');
echo $form->end('Register');
?>
</div>

Actually this my index.ctp in /forms
on clicking on this register what i need is the same what u said If i kept userscontroller ,will it directly wents there to usercontroller and come back to forms .to design forms

Comment: If you want to add additional information, try doing _Edit_ on the main question instead of posting messy code fragments in comments. I have updated my reply to answer your question.